# Read from a file to three parallel array

Tags: c++, arrays, file

As part of my assignment I need to open a file and then read the information into 3 arrays. These information are separated into 3 different columns first one is, Country Code name(is string), second is the population(is int) and the third is the full name of the country. Here is the example of few lines of the file:

- AU 20090437 Australia
- BR 186112794 Brazil
- BU 7262675 Bulgaria
- CA 32805041 Canada
- CN 1306313812 China
- DO 8950034 Dominican Republic

So far I have:

```
void readCntrData(string [], int [], string[], int &size, const int maxSize);

int main()
{
    const int COUNTRIES = 200;
    // maximum size of arrays
    int size = 0;
    string cntrCodes[COUNTRIES];
    int cntrPopulation[COUNTRIES];
    string cntrNames[COUNTRIES];

    string inputFileName = "countries.txt";
    ifstream inputFile;

    inputFile.open(inputFileName.c_str());
    if (inputFile.fail())
    {
        cout << "\n\tPlease check the name of the input file and \n\ttry again later!\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int index = 0;
    while (index < COUNTRIES && inputFile >> cntrCodes[index] >> cntrPopulation[index] >> cntrNames[index] ) {

        index++;
    }

    size = index;
    if (size == COUNTRIES && !inputFile.eof()){
        cout << "\n\tThe input file  \"" << inputFileName <<
        "\"is too big: \n\tit has more than " << COUNTRIES << " items!\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    inputFile.close();
}
```

The issue here few countries have two part names, and my code breaks where the name of country has two parts. I don't know how to ignore the space there and read the whole name.

I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Instead of three parallel arrays, consider one array of a structure that contains the three pieces of data. Makes keeping everything in synch much easier.

Comment: Don't use arrays. Don't use "parallel arrays". Use a vector of structs or classes.

Comment: Fortunately the multi word tokens are at the end of the line. You can `file >> token 1 >> token2 && getline(file, token3)`

Comment: Good job on `while (index < COUNTRIES && inputFile >> cntrCodes[index] >> cntrPopulation[index] >> cntrNames[index] )` It's heartbreaking how many people still try to use EOF here.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Unfortunately I haven't yet learned about struct and classes. thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: Your code is using classes all over the place.

Comment: No time like the present to learn. Anyone who cares if you learn to use a tool this week instead of next week was compiled with -pedantic.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks, I just used your suggestion, and I only get last line of my text file plus "lic" (I think comes from buffer),and Australia at the end :  which is US US 295734134 United Stateslic            Australia                                Do I need to ignore before using the getline?

Comment: Shouldn't need any ignoring. The `getline` eats everything up to and including the end of the line for you. Nor sure where the garbage  would come from. Has anyone shown you [how to use a debugger yet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger)? If not take my word for it, sitting down and spending a few hours figuring out the basics will be one of the best bang-for-buck investments you'll ever make.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks, you were right. the problem was with my txt file, the lines  did not have new line at the end( when I was opening the file in notepad++ and enabling the "show end of the line" I as only seeing CR at the end and not CRLF, I think it was caused by copying file from mac to USB and then opening it on windows, but not sure though). Now I put new line at the end of each line and your suggestions works perfectly. Thanks for your time. I start reading about debugger too :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just cleaning the code up a bit...

- the main problem you ask about in your question has already been addressed by user4581301 in comments: summarily, using `getline` to read the country code will cope with having one or more whitespace-separated words
- since C++11, we've been able to use the `ifstream` constructor to open a filename passed in a `std::string`, and it's often convenient to construct the `ifstream` inside an `if`/`else` construct that then handles the successful-open and failed-attempt-to-open cases
- there's no need to explicitly close `ifstream`s that are going out of scope anyway
- it's good to send error messages to `std::cerr`, so if someone running your program does something like "theprogram > theprogram.output" they'll still see the error messages in their terminal
- no real need to have separate `index` and `size` variables, and something like `num_countries` is a better, more meaningful name
- checking for EOF is a bit of a dark art - I wouldn't recommend using `inputFile.eof()` the way you did because if the last country read was followed by an empty line in the file, you wouldn't have hit end-of-file even though it's "logically" empty thereafter; it's too easy for someone not to notice empty lines at the end of a file when they're working in a editor to create/update the file; checking if there's another non-whitespace character is a more robust approach
- the common size for `int` these days is 32 bits, which can handle numbers up to a couple billion (when signed, or a bit over 4 billion for `unsigned int`); China's population's a bit too close to that for comfort - if you want to write code in a way that should still work 20 or 50 years hence, it's good to think about whether the types will still be large enough to store the values; `int64_t` from [`<cstdint>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) is a better choice.

Revised code:

```
int main()
{
    const int COUNTRIES = 200;

    string cntrCodes[COUNTRIES];
    int64_t cntrPopulation[COUNTRIES];
    string cntrNames[COUNTRIES];

    string inputFileName = "countries.txt";
    if (std::ifstream inputFile{inputFileName})
    {
        int num_countries = 0;
        while (num_countries < COUNTRIES &&
               inputFile >> cntrCodes[num_countries] >> cntrPopulation[num_countries] &&
               getline(std::cin, cntrNames[num_countries]))
            ++num_countries;

        // will see if we can read another character (remember >> skips
        // whitespace by default), rather than check inputFile.eof()
        // which may not be true if there're any extra empty lines after
        // the data...
        char character;
        if (num_countries == COUNTRIES && inputFile >> character)
        {
            std::cerr << "\n\tThe input file  \"" << inputFileName <<
        "\"is too big: \n\tit has more than " << COUNTRIES << " items!\n";
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        // any extra code to actually use the country data goes here...
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "\n\tPlease check the name of the input file and \n\ttry again later!\n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Tony Delroy. very informative response, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

For the last input of each line, you can use getline which reads everything until it meets an Enter key.

You can try this:

```
while (index < COUNTRIES && inputFile >> cntrCodes[index] >> cntrPopulation[index] ) {
    getline (inputFile, cntrNames[index]);
    index++;
}
```

Comment: It's important for the condition to depend on the success of the call to `getline` - otherwise if there's a missing country you'll not notice and leave it empty.  To fix that, you should append `&& getline(inputFile, cntrNames[index])` to the condition (and not call `getline` inside the statement block the loop controls).